# Dynamic span tag within a table cell not loading the text in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I just started learning asp.net and C# and I am trying to setup a table in an asp page. The table will have two columns and one row and both cells have text that can be changed from the db side. I have the following test code which should work based on various sources on the web. However, its not. I am not sure why not. 
asp code:

```
    <asp:table class="pageTitle" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow id="row1">
            <asp:TableCell class="pageTitle" id="cell1">

            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell class="pageTitle" id="cell2" >

            </asp:TableCell>            
        </asp:TableRow>
</asp:table>
```

C#:

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span1.InnerHtml = "span1";
        cell1.Controls.Add(span1);

        var span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span2.InnerHtml = "span2";
        cell2.Controls.Add(span2);

    };
```

After I run this code I am expecting to see `span1` and `span2` in the table cells but I don't see anything. I am not sure what I am missing here. I am seeing the same problem if I use `<asp:Label>` instead of span and I am seeing a similar problem if I try to put a dropdown on the page and populate the values or options from a `.cs` file. Could it be the way I have setup the project in Visual Studio? I am using a web form which I thought would be appropriate.

Comment: I tried it and I see what you expect to see. Just for fun, try adding `Response.Write("<p>Hello, world!</p>");` to your `Page_Load` method. Does that appear on the page? I'm trying to determine whether your method is actually executing.

Comment: It doesn't appear on the page. Any ideas why the method might not be executed?

Comment: It's harder to tell without being able to see the project. Are you sure that the code is in the code-behind for the same page where you've added the table? It it inside a server-side form? Is there also an .aspx.designer.cs file associated with the page? One approach is to just create new page, making sure you're doing it the "normal" way through VS, add these elements, and see if it works. If it does, go back and see what's different between that new page and the previous one.

Comment: I recommend investigating the html of your page in the browser with the browser's dev tool. First make sure that your table exists in the html output, then we can check further

Comment: @ScottHannen I followed your suggestion of creating a new page and it worked with the expected output. The difference between the two pages is that the first page doesn't have any `<@ Page>` tag or any other html tag. I did it like that so that I can include it in the main page like this `<!-- #include file="titleTable.aspx"-->` I guess I need to figure out a different way to include aspx pages

Comment: I haven't used the `<asp:Table>` control much, but dont you need a `runat="server"` on your TableRow or TableCell in order to access it in your code-behind? Or like a `table.FindControl("cell1")`

Comment: If what you want is to create a fragment of HTML that you can reuse across pages, try creating a user control (.ascx). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.140)

Comment: @ScottHannen Yeah looks like that's what I am going to have to learn. @zgood I tried what you said but the problem is the `Page_Load` method is not called if don't use `<@Page>` directive or at least that's how I understand it

Answer (score 0):

do u have line like this on your page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default7.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default7" %>
```